# Is there a way to pipe data from one RMD to another?

Tags: r, r-markdown, workflow

I am setting up a project where I will be doing all my data cleaning, management, and analysis in a single rMarkdown file.

However, after cleaning, I want to then generate a codebook based on the cleaned dataframe(s) in a separate file (using a package called `codebook` if that is helpful).

However, RMDs by their nature usually are designed to be self-contained.

Is there a way to basically "pipe" a dataframe from the cleaning.rmd into the codebook.rmd.

My workflow would be something similar to:

```
df_raw %>% cleaning.rmd (which creates df_clean) %>% codebook.rmd
```

I have looked into child documents, but it seems to be more loading multiple RMDs into a single one, instead of a single RMD into multiple.

Thank you for any suggestions that you might have!

Comment: Perhaps wrap with `{}`

Comment: The simple solution is to have one Rmd write output to a file and the next Rmd  read it in from that file. This is actually nice--you shouldn't need to re-run your data cleaning script every time you want to work on something downstream.

Comment: The  more advanced solution is to look into something like the `targets` package.

Comment: @GregorThomas Generating an intermediate file was my original plan, but my boss prefers not having to generate these types of files if they can help it. I will look into ```targets``` though. Thank you!

Comment: Running an Rmd file doesn't "return" anything. If you use `rmarkdown::render` to process each file you could potentially chain them together, having `cleaning.rmd` internally call `codebook.rmd` and pass in an environment with the `envir` argument of `render()`. But that seems a lot less flexible.